# Python rstrip not giving wanted results

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying a basic operation with rstrip but it does not yield the results.

```
t='1.1.1.1:3389, \n2.2.2.2:5989, \n'
t.rstrip(',')
t2 = t.rstrip(',')
```

This results in t2 value being '1.1.1.1:3389, \n2.2.2.2:5989, \n', however I would like to remove the last ',' at the end...

Is there something that I am not doing correctly? I was reading about rstrip returning a copy so I used a new variable t2 but no success...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `rstrip` removes the right-most characters if possible. Your right-most character is not a comma but a linefeed so it doesn't remove anything. You want to use `rstrip(",").rstrip()` to remove all the right blanks.

Comment: @Guimoute i think you mean `t.rstrip().rstrip(",")` ?

Comment: Thank you all, this code t.rstrip(', \n') works. I guess I need to add back the \n later...? A bit inconvenient haha

Comment: @HugoFournier If you have control over the whole thing, maybe check whether you actually need `\n` anywhere in between, and add it only at the very latest occasion. Do you need to have it in the first place?